# 'Variável' não inicializada usada nessa função?

Tags: c, string, variáveis

Após a compilação do programa, recebe 2 warnings do mesmo tipo:

> "warning: 'frase' is used uninitialized in this function"

e

> "warning: 'palavra' is used uninitialized in this function"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *alocar_palavra(char *palavra);
char *alocar_frase(char *frase);

int main(){

  char *frase, *palavra;
  frase = alocar_frase(frase);
  palavra = alocar_palavra(palavra);
  printf("%s", frase);
  printf("%s", palavra);

  return 0;
}

char *alocar_palavra(char *palavra){

  palavra = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
  scanf(" %s", palavra);

  return palavra;
}

char *alocar_frase(char *frase){

  char letra;
  int k = 0;
  frase = NULL;

  do{
      letra = getchar();
      frase = (char*)realloc(frase, (k+1)*sizeof(char));
      frase[k] = letra;
      k++;
  }while((letra != '$') && (letra != '\n'));

  return frase;
}
```

Comment: `realloc` so pode ser chamado depois de `malloc`, `calloc`, ou `realloc` como indica a [documentação](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), caso contrário pode obter resultados indeterminados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem porque passar as variáveis se logo depois irá descartar seus valores, quando está fazendo isso sem valor causa esse problema.

O código pode ser bem melhorado, perceba tudo o que eu fiz. Pra falar a verdade, essas variáveis do `main()` nem são necessárias.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *alocar_palavra() {
    char *palavra = malloc(20);
    scanf(" %s", palavra);
    return palavra;
}

char *alocar_frase() {
    char letra;
    int k = 0;
    char *frase = NULL;
    do {
        letra = getchar();
        frase = realloc(frase, k + 1);
        frase[k++] = letra;
    } while (letra != '$' && letra != '\n');
    return frase;
}

int main() {
    char *frase = alocar_frase();
    char *palavra = alocar_palavra();
    printf("%s", frase);
    printf("%s", palavra);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/4tNNaA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fzoxamwg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Initialization.c).