# Que tipo de entrada de dados é esta? scanf("%m[^ ]")

Tags: c, entrada-de-dados

Encontrei isso em um programa C:

```
int k;
char* nometreino;
char* nometeste;

FILE* arquitreino;
FILE* arquiteste;

scanf("%m[^ ] %m[^ ] %d", &nometreino, &nometeste, &k);

arquitreino = fopen(nometreino, "r");
arquiteste = fopen(nometeste, "r");
```

Nesse caso ele esta declarando as variáveis para abrir o arquivo, porem me perdi nesse scanf `%m[^ ]` e apos ele, vai ser aberto o arquivo que estao nas variaveis `nometreino` e `nometeste` certo?

Como funciona?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é algo padrão e a maioria dos compiladores não aceitam isto, portanto é um bom motivo para não usar.

Se for usar o GCC pode aplicar para o `scanf()` alocar a memória necessária para o dado que será armazenado na variável ali. Então o primeiro *placeholder* criará um *buffer* para armazenar um dado e isto será apontado por `nometreino`, assim como o segundo para a outra variável.

Sem isto neste código daria um erro porque em lugar algum este espaço foi reservado antes.

Não sei detalhes mas meu entendimento é que ele sempre usará um `malloc()` para fazer isto, o que nem sempre é o que deseja.

Isto teria o mesmo efeito:

```
int k;
char* nometreino = malloc(101);
char* nometeste = malloc(101);
scanf("%100s[^ ] %100s[^ ] %d", &nometreino, &nometeste, &k);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/CreateBuffer.c).

Na verdade quase isto, porque está alocando um espaço provavelmente maior do que precisa e se precisa mais não tem como usar, mas é mais ou menos assim que as pessoas usam. Tem uma [resposta que fala sobre algo mais adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177413/101), ainda que seja uma forma ingênua de fazer ([outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219721/101)). neste caso provavelmente o `malloc()`poderia ser substituído por um *array* na *stack*.